# jQuery tabs toggle loop

Tags: jquery

What I'm looking for is a more efficient way of doing what I do here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#toggleTwo').click(function(){
                    $('#one').slideToggle();
                    $('#two').slideToggle();
                 });
                 $('#toggleThree').click(function(){
                    $('#two').slideToggle();
                    $('#three').slideToggle();
                 });
            });
```

And the HTML is:

```
<div class="col-md-10" id="toggleTwo">
toggle
</div>
<div id="two">
two
</div>

<div class="col-md-10" id="toggleThree">
toggle
</div>
<div id="three">
three
</div>
```

What I'm looking for to do is simply; click on one "tab" (where it says toggle) and the "child" shall be displayed, and the others needs to be closed. I'm thinking something about a loop or something, but not really sure how to solve the problem. My solution works, but when I got 20 tabs it's not too efficient.

```
<div class="col-md-10 toggle box_top" id="toggleOne">
                        <h4>2. Välj hej</h4>
                        hejsan

                        <div  class="childtoggle" style="display:block">
                            <div class="box1">
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-12 checkbox2">
                                    <span>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc">
                                        <label for="c1" class="c1c">Har ännu ingen e-handel</label>
                                    </span>

                                    <span>
                                        Lorem Ipsum 100kr
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-12 checkbox2">
                                    <span>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc">
                                        <label for="c1" class="c1c">Har ännu ingen e-handel</label>
                                    </span>

                                    <span>
                                        Lorem Ipsum 100kr
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-12 checkbox2">
                                    <span>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc">
                                        <label for="c1" class="c1c">Har ännu ingen e-handel</label>
                                    </span>

                                    <span>
                                        Lorem Ipsum 100kr
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-12 checkbox2">
                                    <span>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc">
                                        <label for="c1" class="c1c">Har ännu ingen e-handel</label>
                                    </span>

                                    <span>
                                        Lorem Ipsum 100kr
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-12 checkbox2">
                                    <span>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc">
                                        <label for="c1" class="c1c">Har ännu ingen e-handel</label>
                                    </span>

                                    <span>
                                        Lorem Ipsum 100kr
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-10 box2">
                                    <div class="btn2 btn-primary gonext">Spxara och gå vidare</div>

                                    <div class="video"></div>
                                    <div class="video-info">
                                        test:<br />
                                        Test, test, test
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-10 toggle box_top" id="toggleTwo">
                        <h4>2. Välj hej</h4>
                        hejsan

                        <div  class="childtoggle">
                            <div class="box1">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li class="nav active"><a href="#A" data-toggle="tab">A</a></li>
                                            <li class="nav"><a href="#B" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
                                            <li class="nav"><a href="#C" data-toggle="tab">C</a></li>
                                    </ul>

                                        <!-- Tab panes -->
                                        <div class="tab-content">
                                            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="A">Content inside tab A</div>
                                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="B">Content inside tab B</div>
                                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="C">Content inside tab C</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-10 box2">
                                    <div class="btn2 btn-primary gonext">Spxara och gå vidare</div>

                                    <div class="video"></div>
                                    <div class="video-info">
                                        test:<br />
                                        Test, test, test
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have only those 3 tabs?

Comment: At this moment, yes, but I'll have about 20

Comment: You've a parent call toggle and an other one call childtoggle, fix the right class on the right aprent/children

Comment: Can u show me with an example? haha

Comment: @Alexis I got the same structure as you?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class for the elements that you are targeting and do something like:

```
$('.myClass').on('click' function() { $(this).slideToggle().siblings('.myClass').slideToggle() })
```

But your HTML should be structured like this:

```
<div class="col-md-10" id="toggleTwo">
    toggle
    <div id="two">
        two
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please make a post abut this! Feels like it is what I need

Comment: This will slide the clicked one, but wont slide back the other one.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle, because it's not easy to figure out what you're actually trying to do. @callback: True.

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like this :

```js
$(".toggle").click(function(){
$('.childtoggle').not($(this).find(".childtoggle")).hide(500);
$(this).find(".childtoggle").slideToggle(500);
});

$(".childtoggle").click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
});

$(".gonext").click(function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
if($(this).parent().parent().next(".toggle").html() != undefined)
$(this).parent().parent().next(".toggle").trigger("click");
else
$(".toggle").first().trigger("click");

});
```

```css
.childtoggle{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-10 toggle" id="toggleTwo">
toggle
  <div  class="childtoggle">
    one
<button class="gonext">
Go next
</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-10 toggle" id="toggleTwo">
toggle
  <div class="childtoggle">
    two
<button class="gonext">
Go next
</button>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="col-md-10 toggle" id="toggleThree">
toggle
  <div  class="childtoggle">
    three
<button class="gonext">
Go next
</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add your child in the same div for more visibility and better to manipulate.
After that you've juste to hide not clicked div and toggle the clicked.

Comment: When I click within the content it closes, how can I fix?

Comment: I've update my answer. Add a event.stopPropagation on child click.

Comment: you're awesome! And what about if I want a button within each "tab", and if you click this tab you get to the other tab. How can I do this?

Comment: also, the stopPropagation() function is stopping my "child tab" which uses bootstrap, how can I fix?

Comment: he's stopping your child tab ? i'll update with button

Comment: thanks it works kind of. When I press the second "tabs"s button, the one over opens. So it's reflected, if you can say like that

Comment: Don't forget the stop propagation in the gonext function. It works fine for me.

Comment: I've copy-pasted what you have done, but when I press the button on the first, it doesn't really work. It works the opposite, so the first tab just closes. And when I then open the second and press the button, that tab is closing and the first is opened

Comment: Can't help you without code. Create a unique class name for these tabs. You've maybe some duplicate class name.

Comment: I mean the "gonext", when I press that -> then it opens the previous tab, not the next

Comment: told you i can't help you without see your code.. x) try to remove one `parent()` in the if and next the if.

Comment: Update my awnser with the code, and I use the very same jQuery as you

Answer (score 0):

@mezt here is the working code for this: http://codepen.io/nitinsuri/pen/yOqMKK

You need to hide all the panels other than the default panel initially.

Then based on a class name, you need hide the visible panel then slide toggle desired panel.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggler").click(function(){
        $(".toggle-panel:visible").hide();
  $("#" + $(this).data('togglePanel') + ".toggle-panel").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="col-md-10 toggler" data-toggle-panel="two">toggle 2</li>
    <li class="col-md-10 toggler" data-toggle-panel="three">toggle 3</li>
</ul>

<div id="two" class="toggle-panel">two</div>
<div id="three" class="toggle-panel" style="display: none">three</div>
```

Instead of the inline style to hide the panels, you can hide all the panels by default and then use a class to display the default pane.